# Symfony 2.3 Vs ~2.3? What is the better choice?

Tags: symfony

I am working on a project with Symfony2. We decided to work with version 2.3 due to the fact that sf2.3 is an LTS. Also, I follow the development of versions ~2.3. But sometimes I see new interesting features in all updates.

I am happy when I see new features. I am sad when I remember that my version is locked. I am afraid that non LTS versions can cause some problems in the feature. What the better choice? Stability of LTS or new amazing features? Can I safe me from any troubles testing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer will be depending from your project phase. 
If you project on development phase and still will be there at least 6 month it will be better  use latest stable development version.
When your project on support phase it's better select LTS version.

For example in my project with stay on LTS version because currently mostly of all no new features developed, just bugfixing and some improvement.

Non LTS version just required spend additional time to upgrade framework version and make project compatible to it. 
Also please notice that Non LTS version not say that it not stable version. It's just have short support term. So when version 2.6 will be release you will be need update your 2.5.1 version.

Comment: And what happens If 2.4 or 2.5 meet a bug? LTS is mantained for three years. 2.4 and 2.5 no.

Comment: Bug will be fixed in version 2.6 or 2.5.1 (that released few days ago). So you will need update your SF version to new one. With LTS version you know that bugfix update not break your system. With no LTS update can break existing functionality.

Comment: But, ... when 2.6, ... 2.7 won't be mantained? I am not afraid "today". I need to be sure that in the future the code I am working on is always stable. Do you think stay on ~2.3 will be secure, in the future, like stay on 2.3?

Comment: Yes idea for No LTS version it's update your sf2 applicate together with it (this is guarantee that you have latest stable version with all bugfix). If you don't have time do that, select LTS version and stay on it till no new LTS version released.